# Check if record exists, if yes "update" if not "insert"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, sql-server-2000, upsert

I want to check table `PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER` if any records exists for 
`strClientID` update `timeValid` for +30 if no records for `strClientID` insert to `premium_service_user` table.

What am I doing wrong?

It increases `timeValid` for +30 days but inserts another row too.

```
SELECT @pre_var = count(*) 
FROM PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER 
WHERE strClientID = @strClientID

/* bronze premium - 200 cash */
IF @Premium = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER 
        (strClientID, timeReg, timeValid, bCurrent, durum) 
    VALUES 
        (@strClientID,getdate(),getdate() + 30,'1','1')

    UPDATE TB_USER 
    SET cash = cash+200 
    WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
END

IF @Premium = 1 AND @pre_var = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER 
        SET timevalid = timevalid+30 where strClientID = @strClientID
    UPDATE PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER 
        SET bCurrent = 1 where strClientID = @strClientID
    UPDATE TB_USER 
        SET cash = cash+200 WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
END
```

Comment: In addition to the fix found below, I would also suggest that you combine the UPDATE statements into a single statement for PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem was running the first `if` without regard to the value of `@pre_var`.

This is a slightly different way of doing it which will be slightly more efficient if `PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER` is large.

```
if @Premium = 1
  begin
    if exists(Select 1 From PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER Where strClientID = @strClientID)
      BEGIN
        update PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER set timevalid = timevalid+30 where strClientID = @strClientID
        update PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER set bCurrent = 1 where strClientID = @strClientID
        UPDATE TB_USER SET cash = cash+200 WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
       END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER (strClientID, timeReg, timeValid, bCurrent, durum) VALUES (@strClientID,getdate(),getdate() + 30,'1','1')
        UPDATE TB_USER SET cash = cash+200 WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
       END
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateProcessed
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Processed_Status NVARCHAR(256)
    SET @Processed_Status = 'ACTIVE'
    IF(@Processed_Status <> 'Processed')
    BEGIN
       SET @Processed_Status = 'Active'
       UPDATE ST_JnlMediumMoveNew
       SET ST_JnlMediumMoveNew.Process_Status = @Processed_Status 
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You're counting the rows, but not using it in your decision making. Here is a decision structure that may be useful

```
Select @pre_var = count(*) From PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER Where strClientID = @strClientID

IF @pre_var = 0
BEGIN
    /* Run Insert Code Here */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    /* Run Update Code Here */
END


IF @Premium = 1 
BEGIN
    /* Run Premier Members Update Code Here */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    /* Run Non-Premier Members Update Code Here */
END
```

Or this one..

```
IF @pre_var = 0
BEGIN
    /* Run Insert Code Here */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @Premium = 1 
    BEGIN
        /* Run Premier Members Update Code Here */
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        /* Run Non-Premier Members Update Code Here */
    END
END
```

Comment: but if count returns me 1 that means record exist on table. i want to do is if row exist on table do update. doesnt ur suggestion mean if count returns 0 do update?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are checking the wrong variable in the first IF Statement.   If @Premium = 1 then you will see this behavior.

```
/* bronze premium - 200 cash */
IF @pre_var = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER (strClientID, timeReg, timeValid, bCurrent, durum) VALUES (@strClientID,getdate(),getdate() + 30,'1','1')
UPDATE TB_USER SET cash = cash+200 WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
END

IF @Premium = 1 AND @pre_var = 1
BEGIN
update PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER set timevalid = timevalid+30 where strClientID = @strClientID
update PREMIUM_SERVICE_USER set bCurrent = 1 where strClientID = @strClientID
UPDATE TB_USER SET cash = cash+200 WHERE strAccountID = @strClientID
END
```