# How to update row in PHP/mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I import outlook contacts file into my database and then display it into html table. The table is created and everything is ok, but when I try to upload it a second time, all names and information is doubled. So what I want to do is **if the first name and the last name already exists** just to update the row and all cells in that row and not insert that row over and over again.

```
"CREATE TABLE contacts(PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(PID),first_name CHAR(80),middle_name CHAR(80),last_name CHAR(80)"
```

I tried with on duplicate key update/replace but it didnt work.

```
"INSERT INTO contacts (first_name,middle_name,last_name)
VALUES ('$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name')"
```

I guess my problem is in the auto_increment and primary key but I don't really understand how they work and how to do that.

Comment: So. make (firstname,lastname) a key

Comment: So like that?
PRIMARY KEY(first_name,last_name)?

Comment: It doesn't need to be PRIMARY. Just UNIQUE.

Comment: I believe your question is answered here: [How do I update if exists, else insert?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql

Comment: You will have problems with this solution though - we have more than one Richard Jones in our address book.

Comment: How do you export the data from Outlook?

Comment: Just using the export contacts function in outlook and then upload it with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INSERT` would never "update" your existing record, because you're missing the "on duplicate key" business:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (field1, field2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UDPATE field1=VALUES(field1), field2=VALUES(field2)
```

and of course, this will only work if the INSERT would actually cause a duplicate key violation. The only unique index you have in your table is the primary key, and you're not inserting a value into it at all, so there will NEVER be a duplicate key violation.

You probably want an `UPDATE` query instead:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET field1='value for field1', field2='value for field2'
WHERE id=$your_record_id
```

Comment: Ok but how i know it is a unique index? How to set first name and last name to be unique indexes?

Answer (score 1):

you could add an hidden field with PID in the HTML, and when you upload to mySQL, you can add a stored procedure to check if it exist or not. If it exists, update if not, insert.

*In case of new user, the PID in the hidden field could be = -1

might want to look at this : [Check if record exists, if yes "update" if not "insert"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189293/check-if-record-exists-update-if-not-insert-stored-procedure)